# Multiple angular js apps sharing the same screen space

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two angular.js apps, app1 and app2. I manually bootstrap these apps, each to its own div. Both app1 and app2 have several states and I use ui router to map app states to partials and controllers and this part works very well for both apps.

The difficulty for me is that only one of these apps should be visible at any given time. Which app should be visible is determined by the current URL (so if the URL corresponds to a state in app1, app1 is visible, app2 is hidden). My question is: how do I show only the app that should be visible? Is there a way to do this without manually showing / hiding divs whenever the state changes?

Answer (score -1):

Communication between angular modules is not possible with regular API, this is not the anglar way. Because you try to determine visibility of an module with url, adding more routes to one module make more sense to me.